# Refactoring IN Subquery, Avoiding Query in a Loop

Tags: mysql-5.5, optimization

I've got a table which was designed as both the current data set for participants, as well as being the historical changeset for those participants. This table has been in use for approximately three years, with 60M records at this time, give or take.

I need to get the current data set for all participants in a group; prior to realizing just what the table really *was*, I used this simple query:

```sql
SELECT ... -- Long list of desired columns, but not *
FROM eb
WHERE employer_id = @AMF
GROUP BY employee_id
```

The `GROUP BY` clause was added when I saw that the result set for my test group was around 1,000 records, when there were only 9 "unique" participants in the group.

Yesterday, my team lead and manager came up with a different solution. First, query all of the participants' SSNs:

```sql
SELECT ssn
FROM participant
WHERE fkDivisionID = (
    SELECT fkDivisionId
    FROM divisionfsk
    WHERE AMFCode = @AMF
)
```

Then, iterate over the result set, querying for the participant:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM eb
WHERE employee_id = @SSN
    AND employer_id = @AMF
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

While it's not the worst solution in the world for the test group with only 9 participants, we have groups with hundreds or thousands or participants, including one group with over 10,000. Hitting the database 10,000 times seems like a really bad idea.

The solution I came up with at the end of the day yesterday was:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ...
    FROM eb
    WHERE employee_id IN (
        SELECT ssn
        FROM participant
        WHERE fkDivisionID = (
            SELECT fkDivisionID
            FROM divisionfsk
            WHERE AMFCode = @AMF
        )
    )
        AND employer_id = @AMF
    ORDER BY id DESC
) t
GROUP BY employee_id
```

My solution has correct logic when tested against the test group, and even runs reasonably quickly (~0.39s). However, when attempting to run against the largest group in the system, the query took 10 minutes before losing the connection, and never completed.

I know `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` is going to be slow, so I tried my hand at refactoring that into something with joins:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT eb.(...)
    FROM eb
    INNER JOIN participant ON eb.employee_id = participant.ssn
    INNER JOIN divisionfsk ON participant.fkDivisionID = divisionfsk.fkDivisionID
    WHERE divisionfsk.AMFCode = @AMF
        AND eb.employer_id = @AMF
    ORDER BY eb.id DESC
) t
GROUP BY employee_id
```

This query appears to return the same result set (and, again, quickly with the test data at ~0.34s), but it is also slow when attempting to query the 10,000+ participant group (loses connection at 10 minutes). How can I improve this?

The user I'm using to connect to this database has full permissions on the database, but nothing beyond the database; I can create a stored procedure, for example, but I can't query any system tables.

The query (or queries, if it comes to that) will be run as part of a web app written in C#, and will be run at most once every 24 hours. There is a query for the `ed` table that is very similar to the one for the `eb` table; the schemas are similar enough that any answer to this question will be applicable to both tables.

Here is the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` output for my last attempt at optimizing the query (using the test group):

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type |    table    | type  |                                    possible_keys                                     |             key             | key_len |               ref               | rows | filtered |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | ALL   | NULL                                                                                 | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL                            | 1024 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | divisionfsk | const | ix_fskDivisionID,ix_AMFCode                                                          | ix_AMFCode                  |      22 |                                 |    1 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | participant | ref   | ix_uniqueSSNCleanDivID,ix_uniqueSSNDivid,IX_participants_group_id,ix_participant_ssn | ix_uniqueSSNDivid           |       4 | const                           |    9 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | eb          | ref   | ix_eb_employerID_employeeID                                                          | ix_eb_employerID_employeeID |    1530 | dbaf_sidewinder.participant.ssn |   70 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

I don't understand everything in a MySQL `EXPLAIN` output, but I do understand that a `type: ALL` and `Using filesort` is going to generally be ugly.

Here's a description of the tables involved:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `divisionfsk` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fkDivisionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `TSYSEmployerID` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `AMFCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ix_fskDivisionID` (`fkDivisionID`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ix_AMFCode` (`AMFCode`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ix_uq_divisionfdsk_TSSYSEmployerID` (`TSYSEmployerID`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_divisionfsk_fkDivisionID` FOREIGN KEY (`fkDivisionID`) REFERENCES `division` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11807 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `participant` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fkAuthenticationID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `fkTpaID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `fkDivisionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
    `middleInitial` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `address1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `address2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `address3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `zip` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `countryCode` varchar(2) DEFAULT 'US',
    `phone` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
    `fax` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `workPhone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `birthdate` date DEFAULT '1900-01-01',
    `gender` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `coverageEffectiveDate` date DEFAULT '1900-01-01',
    `coverageTermDate` date DEFAULT '1900-01-01',
    `ssn` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `ssn_clean` char(9) NOT NULL,
    `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ix_uniqueSSNCleanDivID` (`fkDivisionID`,`ssn_clean`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ix_uniqueSSNDivid` (`fkDivisionID`,`ssn`),
    KEY `IX_participants_group_id` (`fkDivisionID`),
    KEY `FK_participant_tpa` (`fkTpaID`),
    KEY `FK_participant` (`status`),
    KEY `idx_participant_firstname` (`firstname`),
    KEY `idx_participant_lastname` (`lastname`),
    KEY `idx_participant_coverageeffectivedate` (`coverageEffectiveDate`),
    KEY `idx_participant_coveragetermdate` (`coverageTermDate`),
    KEY `idx_participant_email` (`email`),
    KEY `ix_participant_phone` (`phone`),
    KEY `FK_participant_authentication_id` (`fkAuthenticationID`),
    KEY `IX_participant_ssn` (`ssn`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_participant_authentication_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fkAuthenticationID`) REFERENCES `authentication` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_participant_fkDivisionID` FOREIGN KEY (`fkDivisionID`) REFERENCES `division` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_participant_fkTpaID` FOREIGN KEY (`fkTpaID`) REFERENCES `tpa` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=560111 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='InnoDB free: 60416 kB; (`fkDivisionID`) REFER `dbaf_sidewind'
```

Note: There is exactly one record in the `tpa` table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `eb` (
    `id` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tpa_id` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `employer_id` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `employee_id` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastname` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `firstname` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `middleinitial` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `address_line1` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `address_line2` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `zip` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `country` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `employee_status` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `gender` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `remarks` varchar(1400) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_updated` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `employer_name` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `converted_to_participant` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `synced_to_sidewinder` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `notes` text,
    `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `IX_eb_conv2part` (`converted_to_participant`),
    KEY `eb_synced_to_sidewinder` (`synced_to_sidewinder`),
    KEY `ix_eb_employerID_employeeID` (`employer_id`,`employee_id`),
    KEY `ix_eb_last_updated` (`last_updated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=78651856 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Note: I have removed some columns from these listings, as a CYA should they provide too much insight into anything resembling "trade secrets". (Not to mention making the list easier to read; `eb` has a *lot* of columns!) None of the removed columns were indexed, and they were all varchar, int, or enum.

Comment: 'ALL' in this case is just for the outer SELECT that you're doing a GROUP BY, hence the 'tempory table;filesort' It's not as bad as you think. If you could post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements for `divisionfsk`, `participant` and `eb` tables, that would be helpful.

Comment: @DerekDowney, Added table descriptions